# Mount Ubuntu installation with broken MBR

Tags: mount, data-recovery, mbr

I was installing Windows 7 next the Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on one SSD disk. After the installation I was not able to boot Ubuntu. The Win broke my MBR. I did not notice there exists boot-repair and therefore I decided to uninstall Win (I hoped it remove win boot loader and Ubuntu became working). But during formatting it stuck. I had to turn my computer off by power button. Now, the computer says MBR not found.

Fortunately, I have disk copy, but 3 months old without some data. I need to re-install MBR or download my data from /dev/sda2 partition but I am not able to mount it.

`sudo mount -t auto /dev/sda2 /mnt/ubuntu/`

result:

`special device /dev/sda2 does not exist`

When i use

`sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda`

result:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 120.0 GB, 120034123776 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 14593 cylinders, total 234441648 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00011464

This doesn't look like a partition table
Probably you selected the wrong device.

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048    48322559    24160256   83  Linux
/dev/sda2        48324606    58626047     5150721    5  Extended
/dev/sda3   ?    58626048   171147263    56260608    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       171147264   234440703    31646720   83  Linux
/dev/sda5        48324608    58626047     5150720   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

I can not put image yet but Disk utility print [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30574171/mount-ubuntu-installation-with-broken-mbr):

What is the problem? I hope the Ubuntu data are still there...

Comment: Partition table errors cause all sorts of issues. Yours basically looks correct but instead of boot flag on NTFS partition you have a ?. I would see if gparted or any partitioning tools will let you change sda3 to bootable or correct boot flag.  Command line `sudo sfdisk -A3 /dev/sda`  or `parted /dev/sda set 3 boot on`

Comment: Ok, now I can see asterisk instead of question mark. What does the -A3 do? I am still not able to mount any partition. The Win partition prints me:~ $ sudo mount -t auto -v /dev/sda3 /mnt/ubuntu
mount: you didn't specify a filesystem type for /dev/sda3
       I will try all types mentioned in /etc/filesystems or /proc/filesystems
Trying ext3
Trying ext2
Trying ext4
Trying vfat
Trying fuseblk
mount: you must specify the filesystem type

Comment: Your sda3 is NTFS, so you must use that. For info on either parted or sfdisk see `man parted` or `man sfdisk`. That explains parameters.  `sudo mkdir /media/windows` As place to mount to. and then mount sda3: 
`sudo mount ntfs-3g -o rw /dev/sda3 /media/windows`

Comment: OK, I tried to repair disk by boot-repair. Now everything looks fine. I can mount the disk and see everything. The last problem is to install boot loader. Is it difficult to install group to mounted disk?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by group. If you have more than one drive, only use advanced mode with Boot-Repair, otherwise Boot-Repair installs one copy of grub to every MBR. Usually you want different boot loaders in different MBRs if you have them.